# Why the query with distinct and group by is not returning results?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query to get the conferences where the column "city" is equal to the $search.

```
   $cities = Conference::
    where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
    -> distinct()->get(['city']);
```

But I want to also order by the results by the conference 'start_date' column. But like this is not working:

```
$cities = Conference::
   where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
  ->distinct()->orderBy('start_date', 'asc')
  ->get(['city','start_date']);
```

For example if the user introduce "New" in the search autocomplete field the distinct is not working, it appears multiple times for example "Newcastle" instead of appear just once.

Do you know why?

Also like this, using group by, when the user introduces for example "New" no result appears, but it should appear "Newcastle":

```
 $cities = DB::raw("SELECT city, min(start_date) FROM conferences WHERE city LIKE '%search%' 
    GROUP BY city ORDER BY min(start_date) ASC");
```

Search() method to handle the autocomplete search:

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $search = $request->term;
    $conferences = Conference::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

    //$cities = Conference::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->distinct()->get(['city']);
    $cities = DB::raw("SELECT city, min(start_date) FROM conferences WHERE city LIKE '%" . $search . "%'
     GROUP BY city ORDER BY min(start_date) ASC");
    $data= [];
    foreach ($conferences as $key => $value){
        $data[] = ['category'=> 'Conferences', 'value' => $value->name, 'url' => 'conference/'.$value->id.'/'.$value->slug];
    }
    foreach ($cities as $key => $value){
        $data[] = ['category'=> 'Cities', 'value' => $value->city, 'url' => 'conferences/where/city/'.$value->city];
    }
    return response($data);
}
```

The `$data` returned with "`$cities = Conference::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->distinct()->get(['city']);`" shows:

```
[{category: "Cities", value: "Newcastle", url: "conferences/where/city/Newcastle"}]
0
:
{category: "Cities", value: "Newcastle", url: "conferences/where/city/Newcastle"}
```

With " `$cities = DB::raw("SELECT city, min(start_date) FROM conferences WHERE city LIKE '%" . $search . "%' GROUP BY city ORDER BY min(start_date) ASC");`" shows:

```
[]
No properties
```

Comment: Perhaps the rows in the database are actually different (i.e. some of their columns differ), but share the same `city` and `start_date`?

Comment: Just group by city.  Newcastle with two different start days are still 2 distinct results.

Comment: Like this " $cities = Conference::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->distinct()
            ->groupBy('city')
            ->orderBy('start_date', 'asc')->get(['city','start_date']);"? It shows an error "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column start_date which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;".

Comment: Yes, as the error says, start_date needs to be aggregated somehow.  If you only want a city to appear once and it has multiple start dates, which start date do you want it to display?  You could use an SQL aggregate function like `max()` or `min()`.

Comment: Thanks, I want to show the conference with the min() start_date. But its not working, for example if the user introduce "New" dont appears "Newcastle", no result appears.